# Pandas write text description before csv header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, documentation

I am working with pandas datasets that get updated frequently. I'd like to keep every version of the dataset to be able to easily revert in case anything goes wrong.
The problem is, at some point, I kind of forget which dataset has what changes if that makes any sense.

Is there a way to associate a text description with a CSV file? For example, is there a way to add a text description to the top 4 rows for example while saving the CSV file?
pandas.to_csv is kind of straightforward and its documentation doesn't have such any options to enable this.

Is there a smarter way to do this other than manually editing the file using Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1:

You have *N* csv files for the *N* different version, and the files are named in a way (e.g. by creation date-time or by a version number) so that you can trace back. Now you want to know which row in this file was changed when compared to the last file.

When you update the latest file, you can add a column called 'change' and put a mark there for all rows that are updated/added, then you save this as the next version.

Idea 2:

If you are familiar with Git, you just modify the same file, save it, commit the change, and let Git does the rest. You know, Git allows you to compare any two versions of the file.